# Batch - If Else Goto was unexpected at this time

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement, command-line, cmd

I know there are better ways of working with a different language. Though I need this done in Batch. Not even powershell. Yes, I know this is 2016. xD

My issue is "Goto Was Unexpected At This Time"

I don't know if this is possible but I am sure it is.

```
:START_CMD
COLOR 02 & CLS & TITLE COMMAND WINDOW
ECHO. 
SET /P _act=$ || Set _act=za
IF /I [%_act%]==[exit] (
GOTO :LOCK
) ELSE (
IF /I [%_act%]==[lock] (
GOTO :LOCK
) ELSE (
IF /I [%_act%]==[login] (
GOTO :UNLOCK_L1
) ELSE (
IF /I [%_act%]==[path] (
ECHO. & ECHO Current Path: %universalpath% & ECHO. & PAUSE & CLS & GOTO :START_CMD
) ELSE (
IF /I [%_act%]==[check] (
GOTO :HELP
) ELSE (
IF /I [%_act%]==[sudo] (
GOTO :HELP
) ELSE (
IF /I [%_act%]==[report] (
GOTO :SECURITY_LOGIN
) ELSE (
IF /I [%_act%]==[help] (
GOTO :HELP
) ELSE (
IF /I [%_act%]==[whoami] (
GOTO :WHOAMI_NOT_LOGIN
) ELSE (
SET _act=$_act: =%
)

IF /I NOT %_act%==za GOTO :START_CMD
GOTO :START_CMD
```

Comment: The easiest way to debug something like this is to comment out the lines, and then start commenting them back in until you get the error.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen Thanks to your input, and testing what you said. I found a better, more efficient way. Just using... posted*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, where are the last right brackets?

```
:START_CMD
COLOR 02 & CLS & TITLE COMMAND WINDOW
ECHO. 
SET /P _act=$ || Set _act=za
IF /I [%_act%]==[exit] (
    GOTO :LOCK
) ELSE (
    IF /I [%_act%]==[lock] (
        GOTO :LOCK
    ) ELSE (
        IF /I [%_act%]==[login] (
            GOTO :UNLOCK_L1
        ) ELSE (
            IF /I [%_act%]==[path] (
                ECHO. & ECHO Current Path: %universalpath% & ECHO. & PAUSE & CLS & GOTO :START_CMD
            ) ELSE (
                IF /I [%_act%]==[check] (
                    GOTO :HELP
                ) ELSE (
                    IF /I [%_act%]==[sudo] (
                        GOTO :HELP
                    ) ELSE (
                        IF /I [%_act%]==[report] (
                            GOTO :SECURITY_LOGIN
                        ) ELSE (
                            IF /I [%_act%]==[help] (
                                GOTO :HELP
                            ) ELSE (
                                IF /I [%_act%]==[whoami] (
                                    GOTO :WHOAMI_NOT_LOGIN
                                ) ELSE (
                                    SET _act=$_act: =%
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)

IF /I NOT %_act%==za GOTO :START_CMD
GOTO :START_CMD
```

By the way, do you think `SET _act=$_act: =%` can work? It seems a simple problem, do you think so?

Comment: Thank you for your post! I have learned from this. Simple things are easy to be missed.

Comment: in this case,we don't need a single `else` (yes, theoretical the `else`s improve performance, but you wouldn't feel the difference of a few milliseconds)

Comment: It's right. And what I think is let OP to make the optimization. It's a good practice. Just as OP's answer. And we need to know where is the real problem.

Comment: @GeminiKeith like you suspected, it was the `SET _act=$_act: =%` which led to a syntax error with the last `if`.

Comment: Ok, congratulations!

Answer (score 0):

```
IF /I [%_act%]==[exit] GOTO :LOCK  
IF /I [%_act%]==[lock] GOTO :LOCK  
IF /I [%_act%]==[login] GOTO :UNLOCK_L1  
IF /I [%_act%]==[path] ECHO. & ECHO Current Path: %universalpath% & ECHO. & PAUSE & CLS & GOTO :START_CMD  
IF /I [%_act%]==[check] GOTO :HELP  
IF /I [%_act%]==[sudo] GOTO :HELP  
IF /I [%_act%]==[report] GOTO :SECURITY_LOGIN  
IF /I [%_act%]==[help] GOTO :HELP 
IF /I [%_act%]==[whoami] GOTO :WHOAMI_NOT_LOGIN  
IF /I NOT [%_act%]==[za] GOTO :START_CMD  
GOTO :START_CMD
```

## This works just as well, and is more efficient.